# Lambda property

Tags: c#, lambda, properties

I'm not sure if this is the right place to be asking this, but I'm not able to contact the author or submit any sort of question.

I'm brushing up on my C# for v6 so thought I'd skim through [Essential C# 6.0](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0134141040) and with regards to properties, there's a piece of code:

```
    // Id property declaration
    public string Id
    {
        get
        {
            return _Id;
        }
        // No setter provided.
    }
    private string _Id = default(string);

    public string ID => Id;
```

I get that the above can be rewritten as

```
public string Id { get; }
public string ID => Id;
```

The section confusing me is this part `public string ID => Id;`.

The author makes no mention of the lambda expression and doesn't refer to it at all, it's just there.  I understand that it exposes another property, but my question is, is there a point / value to having two properties being exposed like this?  I've been scouring documentation on lambda and properties for hours but I just can't find any sort of mention of doing something like this.

Comment: There's absolutely no reason to have those two properties exposed (or existing). You only need `Id`. If someone wrote this in a tutorial, I would be *very* skeptical about any advice they offer. Not only is it useless, but it would be extremely confusing to see two public properties named `Id` and `ID`. The `=>` is simply syntactical sugar for a `get` implementation.

Comment: Note that `public int Id => GetId();` and `public int Id = GetId();` are subtly different in that `=>` will execute `GetId()` every time it is called, while `=` will only execute `GetId` once.

Comment: @Rob Your first answer is actually what I'm looking for, if it was an answer I would have marked it.  I guess the author might have thought he was going to elaborate and remark on it and forgot or something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I've figured it out.  It has to do with `inheritance`, specifically `aggregation` / `composition` where you'll map properties to the existing properties / field within the referenced class.  It came to me while reading [Understanding Association, Aggregation, and Composition](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/330447/Understanding-Association-Aggregation-and-Composit).

As I mentioned in my OP, the issue was specifically related to the necessity of a lambda expression to express a property.

Answer (score 1):

This is lambda expression **([Expression-Bodies Members](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/wiki/New-Language-Features-in-C%23-6#expression-bodied-function-members))** which acts as the body of a function member. Whenever, method description is succinct,  c# [6](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2014/11/20/new-features-in-c-6.aspx) makes it easier to write by using Lambda for function body.

In this particular case, why do you even need the backing field `_Id` ? With Auto Implemented Properties you can even eliminate the backing field.

Also, following example illustrate this point again. Before, c# 6, if you need to override ToString, it would be written this way.

```
public override string ToString()
{
 return ID.ToString();
}
```

In C# 6, this can be shortened to

```
public override string ToString() =>   ID.ToString() ;
```

Comment: I'd suggest to also refer to the documentation on github for the new language features which talks a little bit more about what you can do with expression-bodied members: https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/wiki/New-Language-Features-in-C%23-6

Comment: I get what you're saying, however, what I'm really after, is an explanation as to WHY `public string ID => Id;` exists in his example.  I'm guessing he meant to elaborate on it and simply forgot or something, don't know but I figured it was either a mistake or an oversight and tried to carry on but it just kept bugging the hell out of me to find out what his justification might have been.